# Enemies won't display

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to create a top down shooter, but my enemies won't spawn in. I'm trying to have the enemy move in a diagonal pattern but also be able to bounce off of the wall kind of like a top down bouncing ball. I'm also trying to have a new enemy spawn every 10 seconds, but when I run the program nothing shows up, there is no error either. Can someone please help.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

import random
import time


inPlay = True
width=900
height=700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

#enemy
enemyFrequency=10
enemyPause=enemyFrequency
killEnemy=True

#------------------------------#
#   classes                    #
#------------------------------#



######################################################

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Group):
    def __init__(self,ballX,ballY,ballSpeed,picture2=None):
        pygame.sprite.Group.__init__(self)
        self.ballX=ballX
        self.ballY=ballY
        self.ballSpeed=ballSpeed
        self.image2=pygame.image.load(picture2)


    def move(self):
        for enemys in self:
            self.ballX+=self.ballSpeed
            self.ballY+=self.ballSpeed


    def decay(self):
       for enemys in self:
           if enemys.y > height:
              self.remove(enemys)        

#------------------------------#
#   functions                  #
#------------------------------#

def redraw_game_window():
    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    enemys.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

#------------------------------#
#   main program               #
#------------------------------#


RB=width-player.rect.width
CEILING = 3*player.rect.height            # for ship movement
FLOOR = height - player.rect.height       #

#enemy
enemies=pygame.sprite.Group()
enemySpeed=3
eX=random.randint(0,RB)
eY=random.randint(-height,0)
enemys=Enemy (eX,eY,enemySpeed,'asteroid.png')
t0 = pygame.time.clock()
dt = 0
enemyCount = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while inPlay:

    redraw_game_window()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            inPlay=False


    #enemies spawning     
    if dt < nSeconds:
        t1 = time.process_time()
        dt = t1 - t0
        enemies.add(enemys)
    else:
        enemyInstance = Enemy()
        enemyCount += 1
        t0 = time.clock()
        dt = 0
    enemys.move()            


    enemys.decay()


    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I think `enemys.draw(screen)` should be `enemies.draw(screen)` in function `redraw_game()`. It's confusing that you have both `enemys` and `enemies` variables.

Answer (score 1):

I hacked your code to the point where it seemed to be doing what the code describes, and what matches your question.  There were a lot of things missing in this code, maybe you cut them out before posting to SO to make the code shorter.

The crux of the problem is the handling of the enemy sprites.  I don't know if it was by design, but the original code was defining what seemed like a sprite, but based on a sprite *group*.

So I modified the code based on the idea that `enemies` should be a global sprite group, and went from there "fixing" things.  There was no `Player` class defined, I added one.  I could not follow the timing code, it was using `pygame.time.clock()` (which is an object) as a time value. It *seemed* like this code was keeping a delta, and counting time to respawn a new enemy, I had to re-write this bit to get it to work - my apologies.

The other comment I want to make - sprites can define an `update()` function.  This function should handle the position changes and appearance of the sprite.  PyGame sprite groups will handle the calling of this function automatically (if it's defined) in the sprite group `update()` meta-call.  This gives the program a clean and simple way to handle sprite animation.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

import random
import time


inPlay = True
width=900
height=700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

#enemy
enemies        = pygame.sprite.Group()  # Holds all enemy sprites
enemyFrequency = 1000  # milliseconds between enemy spawn
killEnemy      = True
enemyCount     = 0

#------------------------------#
#   classes                    #
#------------------------------#

######################################################

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('player.png').convert_alpha()
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (100,100)  # TODO  - position properly

    def update(self):
        # TODO
        pass


class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ballX, ballY, ballSpeed, picture2=None):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.ballSpeed = ballSpeed
        self.image     = pygame.image.load(picture2).convert_alpha()
        self.rect      = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( ballX, ballY )

    def update(self):
        global enemies    # group of all enemy sprites (to which this sprite belongs)
        global height     # window height
        self.rect.x += self.ballSpeed
        self.rect.y += self.ballSpeed

        # decay the enemy
        if ( self.rect.y > height ):
            enemies.remove(self)        # went off screen, delete it

#------------------------------#
#   functions                  #
#------------------------------#

def redraw_game_window():
    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    enemies.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

#------------------------------#
#   main program               #
#------------------------------#

player = Player()
RB=width-player.rect.width
CEILING = 3*player.rect.height            # for ship movement
FLOOR = height - player.rect.height       #

# start with 3 enemies
for i in range( 3 ):
    enemySpeed = 3
    eX=random.randint(0,RB)
    eY=random.randint(-height,0)
    enemies.add( Enemy(eX,eY,enemySpeed,'asteroid.png') )

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
last_enemy_spawn_time = 0

while inPlay:
    time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            inPlay=False

    # is it time to spawn a new enemy?
    if ( time_now - last_enemy_spawn_time > enemyFrequency ):
        last_enemy_spawn_time = time_now  # reset timer

        #enemies spawning     
        eX=random.randint(0,RB)
        eY=random.randint(-height,0)
        enemies.add( Enemy(eX,eY,enemySpeed,'asteroid.png') )
        enemyCount += 1

    enemies.update()         # call the update() of every sprite   
    redraw_game_window()
    #enemies.decay() -- MOVED INTO Enemy.update()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```